# Show relationships between 3 numerical values and turn the horizontal axis into a logarithmic scale

Tags: powerbi

Which type of visualisation I need to choose if I want to show relationships between 3 numerical values and turn the horizontal axis into a logarithmic scale? The worksheet data would include grouped sets of values and you wanted to show patterns in large sets of data, for example by showing linear or non-linear trends, clusters, and outliers?

- Bubble Chart
- Bar Chart
- Treemap
- Pie Chart

Comment: Can you give an example of such a chart via link or upload?

Comment: @AlexisOlson I don't have. it is a theoretical  question

Answer (score 0):

A bubble Chart is the correct option.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).